# C++ - Unable to instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

(I'm pretty new to C++, so hopefully this is just a rookie mistake)

I'm having problems in my code, where I have a class "Player" that needs a number of attributes, which I'm try to give it though the use of abstract classes as such:

```
//player.h

class Player : public IUpdate, public IPositionable, public IMoveable, public IDrawable
{
public:
    Player(void);
    SDL_Rect get_position();
    void move(Uint32 dTime);
    void update(Uint32 dTime);
    void show(SDL_Surface* destination);
    ~Player(void);
private:
    SDL_Surface texture;
    int x, y;
};
```

And I'm overriding the pure virtual functions as such:

```
//Player.cpp
Player::Player(void)
{
}

SDL_Rect Player::get_position()
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.h = 0;
    return rect;
}

void Player::move(Uint32 dTime)
{

}

void Player::update(Uint32 dTime)
{
    move(dTime);
}

void Player::show(SDL_Surface* destination)
{
    apply_surface(x, y, &texture, destination, NULL);
}

Player::~Player(void)
{
}
```

However I keep getting the compilation error: `C2259: 'Player' : cannot instantiate abstract class`

As far as I can see, the pure virtual functions should be overridden, which my Google-searches have told me, would have made Player non-abstract, yet Player still appears to be abstract.

EDIT:
The pure virtual functions:

```
class IPositionable
{
public:
    virtual SDL_Rect get_position() = 0;
private:
    int posX, posY;
};

class IUpdate
{
public:
    virtual void update (Uint32 dTime) = 0;
};

class IMoveable
{
public:
    int velX, velY;
    virtual void move(Uint32 dTime) = 0;
};

class IDrawable
{
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
private:
    SDL_Surface texture;
};

class IHitbox
{
    virtual void check_collsion() = 0;
};

class IAnimated
{
    virtual void next_frame() = 0;
    int state, frame;
    int rows, columns;
};
```

Comment: `Player` must override **all the pure virtual functions** of the classes through which it derives.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
class IDrawable
{
public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
};

void Player::show(SDL_Surface* destination)
{
    apply_surface(x, y, &texture, destination, NULL);
}
```

Note that `Player::show(SDL_Surface* destination)` does not override the pure virtual method `IDrawable::show()`.
In order to override the method you need to exact same function signature in derived class(*only co-variant return types are allowed*)
What you have right now is a method named `show()` in derived class which *[hides](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html)* the method named `show()` in Base class it does not override it. Since you don;t provide definitions for all pure virtual functions of your class `Player` compiler rightly tells you it is an Abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that instead of overriding a pure virtual function of one of the bases, you've instead declared and defined a function with a subtly different signature, as in the following:

```
struct base {
    virtual void foo(double d) = 0;
};

struct derived: base {
    // does not override base::foo; possible subtle error
    void foo(int i);
}
```

You might want to double-check your code by reviewing it. If you were using C++11, you'd be able to mark your functions `override` to catch such errors.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is abstract - i.e. something is not defined but just declared.

You need to define all those methods. As I do not have the declarations for those classes I cannot advise you on what methods you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ a function is not virtual unless it is specifically written:

```
virtual void move(Uint32 dTime);
```

A [pure virtual function](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/) is defined like this:

```
virtual void move(Uint32 dTime) = 0;
```

The "interfaces" you inherit from (notice that this is [multiple inheritance](http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060225/virtualBaseClass/).. C++ doesn't differ interfaces from classes) have pure virtual functions you didn't implement thus making your class abstract.

Comment: I totally forgot to add the pure virtual functions. They have been edited in to the original post now.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is caused by missing an override of a pure virtual function - maybe just a subtle sigature difference.

I would expect the compiler would tell you which function is still not overriden, something like (vc9):

```
C2259: 'Player' : cannot instantiate abstract class
due to following members:
'void IUpdate::update(void)' : is abstract
virtualclass.cpp(3) : see declaration of 'IUpdate::update'
```

If your compiler didn't report this, you could check by removing the inherited interface one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately it tells me nu such thing :(

Comment: @user1673234 which compiler and version you are using